# How do I fix screen with no icons at start-up?

Tags: startup, icons

I just downloaded Ubuntu from a CD and the installation went great. I started up the computer, selected Ubuntu, put in name and password, but then the screen I get every time is just the Ubuntu pink desktop image with no Icons at all. The mouse moves fine, but the screen has nothing on it. I can right click with the mouse and create new folders. Other than that, pretty much nothing. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you hold the left mouse button down, can you drag and create a selection rectangle? Can you right-click on the desktop and create a new folder? Does pressing `Alt`+`F2` and running `unity --reset` help? How about `compiz --replace`? Does switching to Unity 2D avoid the problem? (To switch to Unity 2D, log out, click the Ubuntu logo on the login screen, and change it from `Ubuntu` to `Ubuntu 2D`; then log back in.) What version of Ubuntu are you running? The best way for you to provide all this information is by **editing your answer**, so it is as though you had provided it initially.

Answer (score 1):

The `unity --reset` command did the trick. Thank you!