# Linux kernel upgrade to 3.11.4 in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, kernel

I upgraded to `kernel 3.11.4` in Ubuntu `13.04 64bit` but lost my desktop (no icons, only wallpaper displaying). Removed the upgrade with

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.11.4
```

but the desktop problem remains. Tried to renew Grub-loader in advanced boot, no joy.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [How do I fix screen with no icons at start-up?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/143071/how-do-i-fix-screen-with-no-icons-at-start-up).

Answer (score 0):

After booting (in the GRUB menu) select

> Advanced options for Ubuntu

There you will find several older kernels to boot from. Try one after another until you find one where the apparent graphics problem doesn't hit you.