# After login, nothing but a black screen

Tags: boot, unity, login, tty

So I tried to install Unity3D and it didn't work out. Each time I started it it would crash. Anyways, I moved on and did some stuff on blender. I switch off my computer and restart it a little later, reach the login screen, type in my password, hit enter and after that... A black screen... I could still move my cursor but other than that, nothing. I tried using Xfce and Cinnamon and still nothing but I can still access TTY though... Any help?

Comment: Black as in blank, i.e, no icons only cursor or nothing nothing?

Comment: Only got a cursor which I can move

Comment: Is it something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9JClV.png)?

Comment: More or less, it's just a black screen, no background

Comment: From personal experience, this has a variety of causes, so finding the right solution is "hard". Try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears), [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/475509/no-desktop-icons-after-update-to-14-04), [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/143071/how-do-i-fix-screen-with-no-icons-at-start-up). Please do post if there's anything.

Comment: Ok here's where I've gotten to so far. None worked, but when I type "startx" in the tty, same thing, black screen, but if I go back into the tty I get "No protocol specified" for about 5 minutes before the tty shuts down xserver

Comment: Removing my graphics Nvidia drivers didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED IT
Reinstalled Cinnamon desktop, removed XFCE and rebooted, it said the disk was full, deleted a few things and I'm now back on track

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem! :D Make sure to mark your question as correct. At least now I have more experience.